# Ember View Inheritance Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am implementing this view logic inheritance into EmberJ and I would like to ask two questions.

```
App.MyBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    // shared logic
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});

App.FirstSpecificView = App.MyBaseView.extend({

  didInsertElement: function(){
    // this views specific logic
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});

App.SecondSpecificView = App.MyBaseView.extend({

  didInsertElement: function(){
    // this views specific logic
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

What is the use of ".on(didInsertElement)"?

How does the use of "onDidInsert" and "didInsertElement" differ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that proficient with Ember JS, and just work with it for 3 months now, but first of all... I've never seen such syntax. I mean:

```
App.MyBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    // shared logic
  }.on('didInsertElement')  //this :D
});
```

There is no need for this 'on('eventName')'. You just simply add function handle to the property and that's all. So it would be like:

```
App.MyBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    // shared logic
  }
});
```

Nonetheless I assume you would like to call method from the superclass in the subclass. Then use it like that:

```
  App.MyBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    // shared logic
  }
});

App.FirstSpecificView = App.MyBaseView.extend({    
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this._super();  //this should call superclass method
    // this views specific logic
  }
});

App.SecondSpecificView = App.MyBaseView.extend({  
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this._super();    //this should call superclass method
    // this views specific logic
  }
});
```